# Generating truth table in CLIPS

Tags: clips

The problem is how to obtain alike binary truth table in CLIPS.
Suppose an ordered initial fact like:

```
(vector -1 -1 -1)
```

The expected result will be something like:

```
(vector 0 0 0 0)
(vector 0 0 0 1)
(vector 0 0 1 0)
(vector 0 0 1 1) 
(vector 0 1 0 0)
(vector 0 1 0 1)
(vector 0 1 1 0)
(vector 0 1 1 1)
(vector 1 0 0 0)
```

The question is: how do I proceed to obtain this result ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do (e.g. what's the purpose of the vector fact containing three negative ones), but if you're just trying to generate permutations you can do something like this:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(defrule generate
   (values $? ?v1 $?)
   (values $? ?v2 $?)
   (values $? ?v3 $?)
   (values $? ?v4 $?)
   =>
   (assert (vector ?v1 ?v2 ?v3 ?v4)))
CLIPS> (assert (values 0 1))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (values 0 1)
f-2     (vector 0 0 0 0)
f-3     (vector 0 0 0 1)
f-4     (vector 0 0 1 0)
f-5     (vector 0 0 1 1)
f-6     (vector 0 1 0 0)
f-7     (vector 0 1 0 1)
f-8     (vector 0 1 1 0)
f-9     (vector 0 1 1 1)
f-10    (vector 1 0 0 0)
f-11    (vector 1 0 0 1)
f-12    (vector 1 0 1 0)
f-13    (vector 1 0 1 1)
f-14    (vector 1 1 0 0)
f-15    (vector 1 1 0 1)
f-16    (vector 1 1 1 0)
f-17    (vector 1 1 1 1)
For a total of 18 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Mr. Riley, I inadvertently posted an answer/question, instead of posting a comment of the "genertaing truth table in CLIPS" after your answer to my problem.
A thousand apologies, and please find my comment in the question/answer section.
Thank you Mr. Riley.

Comment: It's still not clear how you're generating the output from the input in your question. Why is (vector 1 0 0 0) in your output but not (vector 1 0 1 1)?

Comment: It's a mistake on my part, and I just realized it just now. In fact, it was just an example where the last line (vector 1 0 0 0) is added unintentionally.

Comment: If I may, here is a summary explanation of what the program do. The purpose of the problem is to obtain a combination of the states of certain protective devices in an electrical power system network. In fact, the -1 in ordred vector fact correspond to the unknown status of some switching devices after a blackout, and the objective is to combine in a binary decision tree all the possible states for the switches (0: open state, 1 closed state) in order to obtain a sequence satisfying certain conditions, such as a non-radial network structure.

Comment: Therefore, not every combination of the vector fact is a solution to the problem, and an optimal solution has yet to be identified. With this type of problem, the combinatorial explosion makes the solution impractical.  If, for example, the number of variables is 20, we will have 1,048,576 combinations, which is prohibitive and impractical.
The solution is to reduce the number of combinations by using heuristics specific to the problem, which is the difficulty.
Therefore, my question is: how can we use binary decision trees for this type of problem?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Riley and God bless you for helping others.

Comment: I don't know how to go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr. Riley.
If I may, here is a summary explanation of what the program do. The purpose of the problem  is to obtain a combination of the states of certain protective devices in an electrical power system network. In fact, the -1 in ordred vector fact correspond to the unknown status of some switching devices after a blackout, and the  objective is to combine in a binary decision tree all the possible states for the switches (0: open state, 1 closed state) in order to obtain a sequence satisfying certain conditions, such as a non-radial network structure.
Therefore, not every combination of the vector fact is a solution to the problem, and an optimal solution has yet to be identified.
God bless you, Mr. Riley, for helping others.